# why is there a #!perl at the top of .t files?

Tags: perl, testing

I notice that there is a `#!perl` at the top of perl test, `.t`, as far as I know you can't execute it as `./test.t` because that would require them to be executable and use the full path. So why do these files usually have this?

Comment: .t test files at my office are executable and begin with `#!/opt/my-organization/bin/perl` -- don't know about yours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. To tell editors to syntax-highlight the file as Perl code.
2. Optionally, to provide a default set of switches to `perl` when running this file. (See [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun).)

(As an aside, on Unix systems, the extension is irrelevant. If the file has the execute bit set, the OS will consider the file a program, so you can run it. When you try to do that, the OS will look at the first line to determine which command (and arguments) to invoke the program with. However, this is irrelevant here as the OS won’t search `$PATH` for non-absolute paths – it will only search relative to your current directory, so `#!perl` will not work. You want an absolute path in practice.)

Comment: @Aristotle -- you don't necessarily need an absolute path.  If you had the perl executable in the local directory it would also work -- at least on my Macintosh it does.  Try this: create a file, say t.boo, `#!boo\necho 'boo'` and make it executable. Then link `/bin/sh` to `boo` in the local directory.  I think, and this may be system dependent, that when you use `./t.boo` it will work.  I thought it would also search your path, but apparently I was wrong about that.  My little experiment worked on my Macintosh.

Comment: well on my *nix system it doesn't work for a `./test.t` unless it uses the absolute path... e.g. it won't work with just `#!perl` if it's executable. don't know about switches... not sure about the editor argument... (I use the absolute path just because FHS does actually say where the perl binary should be and SUS requires one)

Comment: also vim seems to still do the highlighting the same without the `#!` of course not everyone uses vim... but I guess I assume I should be able to say "get a smarter editor"... and switches ... I don't see the point of using any... I guess if I were using taint tests... so is there any point in me having a #! in my .t's

Comment: If you take out the `#!` line that tells vim the file is Perl, you are forcing it to guess.  In your case apparently you are lucky and it still manages to guess correctly, but what is the point of making it use an unreliable heuristic when you can just use this standard way of specifying the file type?

Comment: @tvanfosson: Interesting. Learn something new every day… I tested that and it works the same on Linux. I fixed the answer to not claim that an absolute path will never work, just that it’s useless.

Comment: @xenoterracide: If I make an empty `foo.t` file in my home directory, vim guesses that it’s a `tads` file, whatever that is. So it’s possible that vim would guess wrong some of the time. (And even if it never does, it may still be helpful to other people looking at your code.) As for switches: some people write their tests to run under taint mode, f.ex.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that, despite the fact that the files are not executable and even it were it would only execute perl if it was in your current directory, it is put there as the "file magic," identifying the file as a Perl file.  The [file](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_file.htm) command can read these [magic numbers](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_magic.htm) and show you what type each file is.  It would require that the magic configuration file be set up to map this onto Perl which, on my Macintosh at least, is not typical.  It does, however, also serve to clearly identify the file to human readers as well as editor programs, too.  Imagine, that you didn't know it was a perl test and only saw the .t extension -- not much information there.  Open it up and, viola, it's definitely a perl file.